# Can I cook a fairy?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Fairies are listed in the same section of your inventory as food and other things you can cook with.

I've received a pink-shaped elixir in a bottle shaped like a fairy, and its recipe says it was made with just one fairy.

Can you use fairies in any other cooking recipe?

Comment: Once again, Arqade in HNQ for the awesome title win.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Technically, *no*, you can't cook them, but you *can* **use** them in recipes to get a better result – the fairy will be released after doing this.

From [this guide](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-cooking-tips-and-tricks/1100-6448564/):

> And if you throw in a Fairy, you’ll get a lot more hearts from whatever you make together. Don’t worry, it won’t actually cook the Fairy.

[This guide](https://www.primagames.com/games/legend-zelda-breath-wild/tips/legend-zelda-breath-wild-how-cook-all-cooking-recipes-list) confirms this behavior, as well.

> Cooking with a Fairy will add considerably to almost any meal you want to make. Don't worry, you won't actually cook the Fairy, but she will hover around the pot and enhance the meal for you. For instance, Fried Egg and Rice made with Hyliran Rice and a Bird Egg usually restores four hearts. However, add a Fairy to that recipe and it restores 14 hearts.

A user [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75078570) says that using a Fairy in a recipe will result in them flying around the pot and strengthening the result.

> You don't actually cook them. They fly around the pot and strengthen the result.

Comment: Do the meals then get the added affect of reviving you from the dead like a fairy does?

Comment: @BlueBarren No.

Comment: Since it is not used in the recipe itself will I be able to get the fairy back?

Comment: @Grirg No. They are "used", just not cooked. You basically release the Fairy and they bless the meal.

Comment: Does this also boost the number of extra hearts you gain from recipes which provide that benefit?

Comment: @txteclipse do you mean restore hearts? If so, yes. I'm not sure about temporary extra heart containers, but it seems like adding a fairy just increases restorative strength.

Comment: @Vemonus I meant extra heart containers, couldn't quite figure out how to word that. I'll try it tonight if I remember.

Comment: "She'll fly around the pot and enhance the meal" -- Nintendo's admirably SFW equivalent of "add 1/2 tsp fairy juice".

Comment: @txteclipse do you mean an extra boost to recipes which temporarily raise the maximum heart containers?

Comment: *No fairies were harmed in the making of this meal*

Comment: So they're basically a sparkly bay leaf.

Answer (score 16):

You can get a unique recipe for only cooking a Fairy. It will produce a potion that restores 8 Hearts per Fairy. It also has a unique sprite. However, it does not allow you recover if you lose all your hearts.